# How to read QComboBox data and storesit into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, pyqt4, qcombobox

How to get the selected item from QComboBox and when pushbutton is clicked stores the selecetd item of combobox into database...

```
import MySQLdb    
import sys    
from PyQt4.QtCore import *    
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def win():

    db=MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','Suhel786','radio')    
    cursor=db.cursor()    

    app=QApplication(sys.argv)    

    w=QWidget()    
    co=QComboBox()    
    co.addItem("A+")    
    co.addItem("A-")    
    b1 = QPushButton("Tap it!")    
    w.setWindowTitle("Combo")    
    hbox=QHBoxLayout()    
    hbox.addWidget(co)    
    hbox.addWidget(b1)

    b1.clicked.connect(b1_action)

    w.setLayout(hbox)

    w.show()

    db.commit()    
    db.close()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def b1_action():    
    print "data is inserted"        

win()
```

Comment: What is the table in the database and what are the fields?

Comment: tabel name is test and fields Blood group of type varchar

Comment: Do you want to insert before what event? Every time you select an item from the QComboBox?

Comment: In short, the selected text of the QComboBox is saved each time the save button is pressed.

Comment: yes if save button is click then data will be saved

Comment: are you cleared about problem statement

Comment: Try my solution and if it works do not forget to mark my answer as correct please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must connect the `clicked` signal of the button with some slot, in this case the slot will be the save method, in this function we will get the selected text through the `currentText()` method of `QComboBox`, and insert it into the database as shown below :

```
class Win(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','Suhel786','radio')
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

        self.db.commit()
        self.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.btn = QPushButton("Save", self)
        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.addItems(["A+", "A-", "AB-"])
        self.layout().addWidget(self.btn)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.combo)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.save)

    def save(self):
        text = self.combo.currentText()
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (Blood) values('{}')".format(text))
        self.db.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Win()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```